# routing to other containers using zuul in docker

Tags: docker, netflix-zuul

I am running two microservices say demo1 and demo2 in two containers using docker. I have configured zuul in demo1. I want to route from demo1 to demo2 that is, I want to access the api in demo2 from demo1.

demo1 is running on port 8080 and demo2 on port 8030 and I want to access the api like this- "localhost:8030/zuultest/test". But the routing is not working. It works fine if I access the demo1 like "localhost:8080/test".

Here is my zuul configuration in application.yml-

```
server:
  port: 8030

#TODO: figure out why I need this here and in bootstrap.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul server

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

zuul:
  routes:
    zuultest:
         url: http://localhost:8080
         stripPrefix: false 

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use *links* option in the docker-compose.yml to link between the two containers.

```
demo1:
  image: <demo1 image name>
  links:
   - demo2
demo2:
  image: <demo2 image name>
```

Then in the zuul:routs:url configuration you can use the conatiner name, *demo2* instead of it's IP.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to ensure that the ports in question are open and accessible from external machine as well.
better still you may route the traffic from port 8080 (default open port ) to the desired port , 8030 in your case. 
For explicitly exposing the port, please refer the link:
https://github.com/wsargent/docker-cheat-sheet#exposing-ports